# ORA-00904: "DEPT_ID": invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys

I have checked all the column names, tried deleting the column and adding a new one but i still get this error. Is there any problem in my SQL query ?

> ORA-00904: "DEPT_ID": invalid identifier

```
alter table Employ add foreign key (Dept_Id) references Department(Dept_ID);
```

Comment: Please add the ddl scripts for your tables employ and department, without knowing the table structure there is no way to help you...

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as tabular initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) PS You have a syntax error. Read the grammar & manual. Show that constituent subexpressions are OK.

Comment: Is there a column Dept_ID in the Department table, which is a key.

Comment: This is going to be a faq. Before considering posting please always google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings, names & line numbers & with & without 'site:stackoverflow.com' and read many hits & answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
SQL> create table department (dept_id number primary key);

Table created.

SQL> create table employ (id         number primary key,
  2                       dept_id    number);

Table created.

SQL> alter table employ add constraint fk_ed foreign key (dept_id)
  2  references department (dept_id);

Table altered.

SQL>
```